# PostgreSQL / WAL-archiving: can I leave archive_command empty when doing image snapshot backups?

Tags: postgresql, azure, wal

I have a PostgreSQL 9.5 instance running off an Azure VM. As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-linux-app-consistent), I must specify a post- and a prescript to tell Azure: *"Yes, I've taken care of putting the VM in a state, so the entire VM/blob can be backed up as a snapshot that can be restored as a working new VM"* and *"Now I'm done"*, thus Azure will flag the backup as [Application consistent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-linux-app-consistent).

In terms of PostgreSQL, I have read [the docs on continuous archiving](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/continuous-archiving.html), that instruct why and how to enable WAL Archiving to allow for backups. And here comes my question:

If I set `archive_mode = on` and `wal_level = archive`, can I leave the `archive_command` empty, and does this even make sense? Or - should I do some kind of archiving here (like e.g. copying the log segments to another location / disk), and is this archiving necessary to ensure a working database upon restoring the VM in my scenario?

I only need to tell the PostgreSQL *"Wait a minute / hold your data-writes (or whatever goes on), while I create a snapshot of the entire VM"*. The plan is to execute `pg_start_backup()` before , take the snapshot and then `pg_stop_backup()`.

I do realize, this method (if it's even valid) is essentially a file system level backup, and [according to docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/backup-file.html), the postgres-service must be shut down for the fs-backup to be valid. [Another place](https://www.compose.com/articles/postgresql-backups-and-everything-you-need-to-know/) I've read that hitting the `pg_start_backup()` should be enough to guarantee for a valid stand-alone physical backup.

Comment: no - If you dont plan to use saved WALS with restore_command later, you dont have to use `archive_command`

Comment: @VaoTsun ok, so if I understand correctly, the WALS are for actual continuous backup, where you use the WALS to patch the "full backup" in order to have an extremely recent restore point at all times? As you can maybe infer, I am a .NET/Azure developer in deep waters ;)

Comment: ah, I just thought I might give you the bad advise :) WALs are used on recovery - you pg_start_backup, copy files, pg_stop_backup and start copied db - it will read from WALs that you have copied and if original server deleted WALS before you copied them - recovery should fail. In fact I never tried to copy VM this way :) lets wait for smbd experienced

Comment: I never tried this too, but I guess that you'll get a "invalid checkpoint record" or similar error when trying to start the copy without acumulated WALs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the snapshots you plan to take are truly atomic, that is, the restored snapshot represents the state of the file system at some point in time, you can just restart the database from such a snapshot, and it will perform crash recovery and come up in a consistent state.

In that case, there is no need to care about WAL archiving or backup mode. You could set `archive_mod = off` and not worry about it.

If the snapshot is not truly atomic, or you want *point-in-time-recovery* (the ability to restore the database to a point in time *between* backups), you need WAL archiving set up and running, because you need the WALs to restore the database to a consistent state.

In that case `archive_mode` must be `on` and `archive_command` must be a command that returns success only if the WAL file has been archived successfully. If only one WAL is missing between your last backup and the time to which you want to restore the database, it will not work.

Comment: Thank you, @Laurenz. It's been a while since I resolved this, but it ended like this: I realized, that Azure VM's running Linux cannot make atomic snapshots (AWS can do this, I think, but this was Azure) whereas their Windows VM's can. The solution - at that time acceptable to customer - was to very briefly in off-hours shut down postgres service to do snapshot (takes about 5-6 seconds in this case). After this, I could succesfully restore the fs-backup of the postgres stuff, since files very obviously not touches while service was offline = while backup was running.